# MongoDB Aggregation pipeline inner array mapping

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb, mongodb-lookup

I am trying to perform a lookup operation between two collections like shown below,

first collection records:

```
{
field1: "FIELD",
title: "sometitle",
secondIds: [
  { 
   value: "nestedval1",
   secondId: "234
  }, 
  {
   value: "netedval2,
   secondId: "342"
  }
  ]
}
```

Second collection record

```
{
 id: "234", 
 secvalue: "somevalue"
},
{
 id: "342",
 secvalue: "anothervalue"
}
```

I am trying to get the output in the below format for matching field1 name "FIELD" inside the first collection.

```
{
 field1: "FIELD",
 title: "sometitle",
 secondIds: [
  {
   value: "nestedval1",
   secondId: "234",
   second: {
    id: "234",
    secvalue: "somevalue"
   }
  },
  {
   value: "nestedval2",
   secondId: "342",
   second: {
    id: "342",
    secvalue: "anothervalue"
    }
   }
 ]

}
```

for aggregation pipeline after matching operation, I still stuck at how to create a lookup operation for retrieving the second collection entry mapped with the first. Can it possible to do it or do have any other way to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
firstCollection.aggregate([
  { $unwind: '$secondIds' },           // Lets first separate the secondIds to as different documents
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'secondCollection',            // second collection name
      localField: 'secondIds.secondId',    // field in first collection after unwind
      foreignField: 'id',                  // field in second collection
      as: 'secondIds.second'               // field to attach values matched
    }
  },
  { $unwind: '$secondIds.second' },        // attached value after lookup will be an array, so let unwind to make it a object
  { $project: { 'secondIds.second._id': 0 } },  // remove _id
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {                              // grouper fields
        field1: "$field1",
        title: "$title",
      },
      secondIds: { $push: '$secondIds' } // group by pushing to an array
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {                 // projection
      _id: 0,
      field1: '$_id.field1',
      title: "$_id.title",
      secondIds: 1
    }
  }
]).pretty()
```

Explanations are in the comments

Comment: Thanks @zishone appreciate your help, apparently my real database structure my first record is also inside one parent record, parent record> first record > second record. So when I group the  items like { parent.field1 : "$parent.field1" } it is giving error for Field path including "." , Is there any way to solve this, thanks.

Comment: Add quotations to dot notation paths: `'parent.field1'`